# how to use typescript typeorm in vanilla js, nest.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I'm trying to build an API with nest.js but I'm making use of vanilla javascript instead of the popular typescript. From the nest docs, I set up typeorm but I can't implement the example code in vanilla javascript, and for some reason, the javascript example isn't available on nest js docs.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private usersRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}

  findAll(): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.usersRepository.find();
  }

  findOne(id: string): Promise<User> {
    return this.usersRepository.findOne(id);
  }

  async remove(id: string): Promise<void> {
    await this.usersRepository.delete(id);
  }
}
```

Any form of assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: This may be their only JS example: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/09-babel-example

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it out ✌️

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#repository-pattern), on the top right corner of the code example, generally you can click to switch between TS ans JS code example:

`JS`

```
import { Injectable, Dependencies } from '@nestjs/common';
import { getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { User } from './user.entity';

@Injectable()
@Dependencies(getRepositoryToken(User))
export class UsersService {
  constructor(usersRepository) {
    this.usersRepository = usersRepository;
  }

  findAll() {
    return this.usersRepository.find();
  }

  findOne(id) {
    return this.usersRepository.findOne(id);
  }

  async remove(id) {
    await this.usersRepository.delete(id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. For some Reason the switch button wasn't giving me the example code in plain javascript.

Comment: Hi @Ayomide! Consider to accept the answer If you think that is correct. Check the Stack Overflow help https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, and welcome to the community!